# 11:1 error Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

i'm working with firebase deploy. i'm integrating firebase and facebook App secret. But i run into problems when trying to get data from a parent document. I have searched the issue on the internet, but it seems that no of the fixes suggested works for me.

**Terminal Error**

```
    11:1  error  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

    ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/prathamwanmode/.npm/_logs/2020-06-14T17_57_59_082Z-debug.log

    Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

**package.json** *file*

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/tslint -p tslint.json",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^5.11.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.17.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: do you have a **tsconfig.json** in your project?
maybe is missing some configuration

Comment: It looks like you are running `eslint` but you are actually using `tslint` in the package.